# aws amplify react-ui authenticator not rendering

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm just trying to use the default provided authentication component but nothing is showing up on the DOM and it's just a white screen.

Setup:

```
npm create vite@latest
 -> react, typescript
npm install
npm install aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react
amplify init
amplify add auth
amplify push
```

main.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode> );
```

App.tsx

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Authenticator>
            {({ signOut, user }) => (
                <main>
                    <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
                    <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
                </main>
            )}
        </Authenticator>
    );
}
```

All I changed from https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator was user.username to user?.username because I was getting an error Object is possible 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out nothing was wrong with the code itself, rather the index.html and  vite config. To fix:

index.html, between <div id=root'> and <script type='module'..> add:

```
<script>
    window.global = window;
    var exports = {};
</script>
```

in vite.config.ts add:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
        },
    },
});
```